# Error Recompiling from Delphi 7 to XE5

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

There is an old project that I need to recompile to XE5 trying to aavoid the weird Twebbrowser errors that the original D7 component brings. The code bellow works great on D7 but not on XE5.

```
    function GetFrame(FrameNo: Integer; WB: TWEbbrowser): IWebbrowser2;
    var
      OleContainer: IOleContainer;
      enum: IEnumUnknown;
      unk: IUnknown;
      Fetched: PLongint;
    begin
      while WB.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
        Application.ProcessMessages;
      if Assigned(WB.document) then
      begin
        Fetched := nil;
        OleContainer := WB.Document as IOleContainer;
        OleContainer.EnumObjects(OLECONTF_EMBEDDINGS, Enum);
        Enum.Skip(FrameNo);
        Enum.Next(1, Unk, Fetched);
        Result := Unk as IWebbrowser2;
      end
      else
        Result := nil;
    end;
```

I've checked and the parameters for EnumObjects are the same on both versions but XE5 says "E2033. Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical".
Any idea how I can recompile this puppy? Thanks. Peace!

Comment: When you have a compiler error tell us which line generates it. Also please try to read the documentation for compiler errors. E2033 is documented.

Comment: the line is  OleContainer.EnumObjects(OLECONTF_EMBEDDINGS, Enum);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a variable parameter, the actual argument must be of the exact type of the formal parameter.

If you get the error I can assume that type of your enum variable is not of type : `ActiveX.IEnumUnknown`, so you can try to change this line in the variable declaration section :

```
enum: IEnumUnknown;
```

to :

```
enum: ActiveX.IEnumUnknown;
```

Comment: Yes. You are right. Thank you very much Aleroot! Peace!

Comment: Perhaps a deeper investigation would be wise here. I'd want to know where this other `IEnumUnknown` is declared, and why it is hiding the other one. Ideally I'd prefer to deal with the problem by removing the faux `IEnumUnknown` from scope if at all possible.

Comment: I agree @David. The other IEnumUnknown comes from MSHTML. The change proposed by Aleroot made the code recompile flawlessly but the app is not working as expected. I use it to fill a government form that is open only a few hours per day so I was able to test it just now. I need to investigate more. Thank you.